# named-checkzone reports 'ns.example.com.ns' has no address records (A or AAAA)

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns, ubuntu-12.04

The first thing I see wrong is that its a recursion problem.  But I'm not sure where the problems lie in my reverse lookup file. `ns` should report back as `ns.example.com` but instead getting `ns.example.com.ns`.  Of course it wouldn't find any entries for that name because there isn't one, nor is it supposed to.

Here's my reverse file:

```
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     ns.example.com root.example.com. (
                              16071990          ; Serial
                         3600           ; Refresh
                          1800          ; Retry
                        604800          ; Expire
                         86400  ; Minimum TTL
)

@       IN      NS      ns.example.com
```

It's not extraordinarily complicated.  What my question is, what other files affect the output for `named-checkzone` when checking a name against the revers file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the whole file?  What domain name is this zone being used for?

You're getting informed that there are no `A` or `AAAA` records in it because there aren't.  Your `NS` record is also relative to the zone, which I'm guessing is wrong (but I can't know for sure because you haven't made it clear what this zone's supposed to do).

You probably want this instead:

```
$TTL    86400
@       IN      SOA     ns.example.com. root.example.com. (
                              16071990          ; Serial
                         3600           ; Refresh
                          1800          ; Retry
                        604800          ; Expire
                         86400  ; Minimum TTL
)

@       IN      NS      ns.example.com.
```

Comment: I admit, I did strip it down as much as I could to see if I could single out the problem.  Turns out it I *was* omitting the `.` at the end of the name. After putting everything back in place, Fixed!